# Windows Form ListView - How to get values of selected Item

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am currently trying to create an app for a shopping basket where you enter an item and then a price in two boxes. On hitting the add button the Item is Added to a List View. You can do this multiple times to add more items to your Basket.

If you decide that you don't want an item in your basket i have a remove button which removes the item which you have selected by clicking on it. My problem is that no matter what item you remove, the values of the last item that you add is taken from the Total instead of the correct one.

My Code for adding an item here:

```
decimal total = numberPicker.Value * priceSetter.Value;
MessageBox.Show("You want " + numberPicker.Value + " " + txtName.Text + " which cost £" + priceSetter.Value + " each. Your Total cost is: £" + total, "My App");
ShoppingCart.Items.Add("Item: " + txtName.Text + "     " + 
                       "Value: " + priceSetter.Value + "     " +
                       "Quantity: " + numberPicker.Value + "     " +
                       "Total: " + (priceSetter.Value * numberPicker.Value)).ToString();
runningTotal = runningTotal + total;
resultBox.Text = runningTotal.ToString();
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ShoppingCartExperiment\Reciept.txt", ("Item: " + txtName.Text + " " + "Price: £" + priceSetter.Value + " " + "Quantity: " + numberPicker.Value + " " + " Running Total: £" + runningTotal + Environment.NewLine));
```

My Code for the removal is here:

```
var selectedItem = ShoppingCart.SelectedItem;
ShoppingCart.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
decimal total = numberPicker.Value * priceSetter.Value;
runningTotal = runningTotal - total;
var SelectedTotal = (priceSetter.Value * numberPicker.Value);
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ShoppingCartExperiment\Reciept.txt", ("You removed " + txtName.Text + Environment.NewLine));
MessageBox.Show(txtName.Text + " has been removed from basket");
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ShoppingCartExperiment\Reciept.txt", ("You new total is: £" + runningTotal + Environment.NewLine));
```

My Project is very small so these two pieces of code are almost all that i have. 
My Thought on this is that whenever i add a new Item, my priceSetter and NumberPicker (quantity) are being over ridden. Selecting the item does not seem to store the values of the item that i have selected, but only of what I added last.

I am quite new to coding to please excuse any Naivety. All help is Appreciated.

Comment: Does the correct item get removed from the list?

Comment: @wonderbell Yes the Correct item does get removed from the ListView, but the Values of the last item you added are removed instead of the values for the selected item.

Comment: And where do you set `numberPicker` and `priceSetter`?

Comment: @wonderbell the numberPicker and priceSetter are Text boxes which the user types in (E.g. they set PriceSetter to £3 and numberPicker to 4 as a quantity). I then put PriceSetter.Value or numberPicker.Value to do any calculations with them such as getting the total.

Comment: So, isn't there a `numberPicker` and `priceSetter` for each row? if so, then you need to get price and number form the `selectedItem`.

Comment: @wonderbell no i dont think there is which is why i think i am having my issue. Would you know how to get the price and quantity from the selectedItem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121715/discussion-between-wonderbell-and-james-tordoff).

Comment: The most obvious mistake is that you adjust the *runningTotal* total variable but forget to update *resultBox*.  The File.AppendAllText() call looks wrong as well, you removed the selected item, not txtName.Text.  Practicing the debugger would be a good idea.